# How to improve the efficiency of PHP mail sending?

Tags: php, email, cakephp-3.0

I'm using PHP to send mails to multiple people in CakePHP.

I'm currently using `foreach` on the recipient array, which contains mail address and names, and send the mails. It's taking quite a while to send mails and can't be done as put recipients' mail as array since there's a tiny different between all mails such as receiver's names.

The mails are using same template but different parameters, is there anyway I can improve the efficiency of it?

Update:  Here is the Email Template

```
<?= $userSex ?> <?= $userName ?>, <br>
Thanks for ordering!<br>
Your order's ID is "<?= $orderID ?>".<br>
You can check the shipping status on our website.<br>
Thank you and hope you have a wonderful day.
```

and here's the code.

```
$mail_list = {
    [0]=>{
        'userSex'=>'Miss',
        'userName'=>'V',
        'orderID'=>'xxxxxxxx'
    },
    [1]=>{
        'userSex'=>'Mr.',
        'userName'=>'Arasaka',
        'orderID'=>'xxxxxxxx'
    }
}
foreach($mail_list as $target) {
    $email = new Email();
    $email->viewBuilder()->setTemplate('notify_template');
    $email->setEmailFormat('html')
            ->setSubject($subject)
            ->setViewVars([
                'userSex' => $target['userSex'],
                'userName' => $target['userName'],
                'orderID' => $target['orderID'],
    ]);
    $emailRes = $email
        ->setFrom(['no-reply@service.com' => 'service announence'])
        ->setTo($target['email'])
        ->setSubject($subject)
        ->send();
    if (!$emailRes) {
        $res = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Every mail sent is slightly different.

Is there a way to improve the mailing speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speed of your mailing will be dictated by the speed of your configured transport  (See https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/core-libraries/email.html#using-transports).

Sending the emails sequentially like this will always take time and it's normally done in some sort of background process (like a cron job).

If you really need to send emails quicker than what a quick transport can offer (for orders and other transactional email, I doubt it) you could investigate other options. Most email API services provide some sort of way to send bulk messages using templates (such as Sendgrid, Mandrill, Mailgun, Postmark, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I'll try the background process(never tried it before tho).

Comment: @RLC_TPJM Check CakePHP "shells", and https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html